# Spring boot - Netty returns 502 status

Tags: spring-boot, netty, reactor-netty

I have a Spring boot based application with reactive netty server. The application is running on multiple nodes with VIP in front of the nodes. Client applications connect to VIP and VIP routes to one of the node with hash based routing. VIP is returning 502 occasionally and VIP says, it received 502 response from Application. Application seems to be healthy and not sure why app is returning 502 occasionally and no logs in application logs related to 502. Is there any way to enable netty logs for 502?  Any clue on how to narrow down the issue?

Our application implements WebFilter and logs each request and response, but unable to see anything related to 502. Is there anything in spring boot netty to enable more logs to triage 502.

Comment: 502 is bad gateway error, implying a proxy/routing issue to your application. You should try a tracert/tracepath to your application in order to see first where is the request failing or a curl --verbose. You cannot see 502 in your logs because the request doesn't reach your app

Comment: @amstegraf It is not failing for all the request. It fails once in a while. I would say 1 out of 2000 requests.

Comment: 1. you could do an integration test multi-threaded with TestNG/postman and run multiple calls and try to see what is happening
2. if all or part of the requests happen in the same time you might have a bottleneck (which can also be from a default config), but first you need to identify the failing system
Try the proposed ways to identify where it is happening and afterwards hopefully it will become easier to understand why

Comment: @amstegraf The integration test was already done and we were unable to reproduce this as it happens only in production. The failure happens during the peak load. Need input on triaging further.

Comment: Also have in mind that most http clients have a very small default on the PoolingConnectionManager / route. in general you have something like 2 connections per route, which means all requests get in a queue and dropped after 100. Maybe you need to increase the defaults (i've seen this issue many times happening, because of default http clients)

Comment: @amstegraf 502 is coming from server. Is there anyway to monitor if it is being dropped?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224014/discussion-between-user1578872-and-amstegraf).